# Parse xml using xpath and java

Tags: java, xml, xpath

Now I am want to parse xml which is coming from webservice. For parsing, I used xpath and java. I have the following code:

```
package test.client;

import com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.NodeSet;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.lang.model.element.Element;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class GetAlarmsCriticalDataCenterLinksDown {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        try {
            GetAlarms ga = new GetAlarms();
            String xml = ga.getAlarms(
                "Alarms", 
                "C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/My Documents/NetBeansProjects/WebSpectrumDemo/src/java/com/xml/Alarms/GetAlarmsCriticalDataCenterLinksDown.xml");
            System.out.println("Response XML:\n " + xml);
            XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            XPath xPath = factory.newXPath();
            String loc = "";
            NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xPath.evaluate(
                "//alarm-response-list/alarm-responses/alarm", 
                new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)), 
                XPathConstants.NODESET);
            System.out.println("Success : " + nodes.getLength());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

and my String xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<alarm-response-list xmlns="http://www.ca.com/spectrum/restful/schema/response"
                     error="EndOfResults" throttle="2" total-alarms="2">
  <alarm-responses>
    <alarm id="51230f5c-11fe-1002-01bc-000c296b3541">
      <attribute id="0x1006e">HBBCPMPLSR1.hdfcami.com</attribute>
      <attribute id="0x11f84" error="NoSuchAttribute" />
      <attribute id="0x118cd" />
      <attribute id="0x11f4e">1361252188</attribute>
    </alarm>
    <alarm id="512313db-c5ee-1003-01bc-000c296b3541">
      <attribute id="0x1006e">HBBCPINTR0.hdfcami.com</attribute>
      <attribute id="0x11f84" error="NoSuchAttribute" />
      <attribute id="0x118cd" />
      <attribute id="0x11f4e">1361253339</attribute>
    </alarm>
  </alarm-responses>
</alarm-response-list>
```

But I'm stuck. I'm getting `nodes.getLength() = 0`.

Any help will be appreciated.
I want to parse whole xml and get the value of the attribute.

Comment: What happens if you remove the namespace from the `alarm-response-list`?

Answer (score 4):

You need to set up namespaces on your `XPath` object.  Use `XPath.setNamespaceContext()` to do this.  Alternatively you could just use local names in your XPath expression, e.g. `//*[local-name()='alarm-response-list']/*[local-name()='alarm-responses']/*[local-name()='alarm']` but the namespace option is better.

A whole lot of information about using namespaces with XPath expressions is already in another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702637/xpath-with-namespace-in-java).

Comment: After getting the length of response I want to get the value of every attribute but i will not getting the value of the attribute.I use the code like

Comment: To get the attribute elements out, iterate over all the nodes in the `NodeList` then cast the nodes that come out into `Element` objects.  From these elements you can get child elements, XML attributes, text content, etc.