# How to parse this xml using XPath in java?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xml-namespaces

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <double xmlns="http://www.somewebsite.com/">2.0</double>`

I'm having a bit of trouble parsing this using XPath 1.0.

this is what i do:

`XPath xpath = XPath.newInstance("/double");
Element returnElement = (Element) xpath.selectSingleNode(doc);`

the return element is null but it should be 2.0.

NOTE: It should be using XPath 1.0

Comment: correct Xpath "/double/text()" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033955/xpath-select-text-node

Comment: @user1516873: Tried that. didn't work. Found the answer here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15240082/841804). it should be "//*[local-name()='double']"

Answer (score 0):

The `double` element is in the `http://www.somewebsite.com/` namespace. Map the namespace to a prefix (e.g. `foo`) and resolve with a qualified expression (e.g. `/foo:double`).

Using the standard API:

```
String xml = "<double xmlns='http://www.somewebsite.com/'>2.0</double>";
Reader reader = new StringReader(xml);
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance()
                          .newXPath();
NamespaceContext context = new NamespaceContextMap("foo", "http://www.somewebsite.com/");
xpath.setNamespaceContext(context);
String value = xpath.evaluate("/foo:double", new InputSource(reader));
System.out.println(value);
```

You can find a sample implementation of [NamespaceContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/namespace/NamespaceContext.html) on [my blog](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.co.uk/2009/05/java-using-xpath-with-namespaces-and.html).