# How to read the particular tag value from xml using java xpath xpression

Tags: java, xml, xpath, tags

Below is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<soapenv:Envelope >
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <inv:GetInvoiceAuthenticationResponse>
         <inv:Header>

            <inv:Cuit>123</inv:Cuit>

            <inv:EmissionPoint>?</inv:EmissionPoint>

            <inv:InvoiceType>?</inv:InvoiceType>

            <inv:ProcessDate>?</inv:ProcessDate>

            <inv:NoOfInvoices>1</inv:NoOfInvoices>

            <inv:Result>?</inv:Result>
         </inv:Header>
         <inv:Invoices>
            <inv:Invoice>
               <inv:Concept>?</inv:Concept>
               <inv:DocumentType>?</inv:DocumentType>
               <inv:DocumentNumber>?</inv:DocumentNumber>
               <inv:InvoiceNumber>?</inv:InvoiceNumber>

               <inv:InvoiceDate>?</inv:InvoiceDate>
               <inv:ResultCode>A</inv:ResultCode>

               <inv:CAE>?</inv:CAE>

               <inv:CAEExpiryDate>?</inv:CAEExpiryDate>


            </inv:Invoice>
         </inv:Invoices>
      </inv:GetInvoiceAuthenticationResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I want to read the `inv:ResultCode` tag . I am using below expression  but it's not working. Please tell what I am doing wrong?

Which path I should give in `xpath.compile`?

```
expr = xpath.compile("//inv:Invoices/inv:Invoice/inv:ResultCode/text()");
```

Comment: It gives you an error or it doesn't give you the right output?

Comment: it doesnt give me the desired output. It doesnt throw any error

Comment: @AnubhavJhalani What do you expect to get and what the code actually outputted? Btw, the XML looks invalid as none of the prefixes are declared (or is it only part of the entire XML?).

Comment: its a  part of the xml . I expect 'A' in the output as you can see 'A' is written in inv:ResultCode tag

Comment: And "what the code actually outputted"?

Comment: result1=expr.evaluate(dc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

               
  nodes =(NodeList)result1;

              
               System.out.println("Number of matching nodes:"+nodes.getLength());


It gives 0 length

Answer (score 0):

See this [other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702637/xpath-with-namespace-in-java) on possible ways, in Java, to query elements in namespace using XPath. Personal preference since I'm not a java guy, I would go with XPath only solution [using `local-name()` and `namespace-uri()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390339/how-to-query-xml-using-namespaces-in-java-with-xpath). The XPath for your case is as follow :

```
/*[local-name()='Invoices'
    and namespace-uri()='namespace-uri-for-inv-prefix']
  /*[local-name()='Invoice'
      and namespace-uri()='namespace-uri-for-inv-prefix']
    /*[local-name()='ResultCode'
        and namespace-uri()='namespace-uri-for-inv-prefix']/text()
```

And if you think you're safe to ignore the namespace, omit `namespace-uri()` filters to simplify (note the risk as explained in the 2nd link above) :

```
/*[local-name()='Invoices']/*[local-name()='Invoice']/*[local-name()='ResultCode']/text()
```