# Extracting value through Xpath expression when there are namespaces

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have the below input xml:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<createdInstances xmlns="http://www.company.com/awd/rest/v1" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <folderInstance recordType="folder" id="2017-08-04-04.22.02.446460F01">
      <link rel="form" type="application/vnd.company.awd+xml" href="awdServer/awd/services/v1/instances/2017-08-04-04.22.02.446460F01/form" />
      <link rel="history" type="application/vnd.company.awd+xml" href="awdServer/awd/services/v1/instances/2017-08-04-04.22.02.446460F01/history" />
   </folderInstance>
</createdInstances>
```

I need to get Xpath for `id` value of `folderInstance` using java(i.e `2017-08-04-04.22.02.446460F01` in this case). I tried with the below expression, but it's not working.

```
//createdInstances/folderInstance@id
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the namespace of the matching nodes. Create a namespace for the XPath (like this in XSLT)

```
xmlns:com="http://www.company.com/awd/rest/v1"
```

and add the namespace prefixes to the element's names. Also add a `/` before selecting an attribute.

```
//com:createdInstances/com:folderInstance/@id
```

If you're using Java [this SO posting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13702843/1305969) shows how to add a *NamespaceContext* to your XPath expression. It also shows another (less precise) approach to only match the local parts of the elements which would look like this:

```
//*[local-name()='createdInstances']/*[local-name()='folderInstance']/@id
```

Comment: I am not using any XSLT here, but I am using Java. How to handle it in java? Any idea?

Comment: Plus one for quick response